# I'm trying to say sad but in a metaphorical sense. Is there a 'simple' word for (light) sad in chinese?

Tags: vocabulary, sentence

I want to express how (lightly) sad something is

e.g. it's **sad** that children do not go out to play anymore.

it's **sad** she couldn't make it to my birthday party.

but all the translations for sad are extreme and usually tied to someone passing away, grieving, etc (悲伤，心酸，难过，遗憾，可惜，惋惜, etc)

Comment: 可惜 is a good one. It can be 'sad' in a sense of 'too bad' e.g. too bad, you can't beat me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**可惜**

[MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqtm=0&wdqcham=1&wdqt=%E5%8F%AF%E6%83%9C)

> it is a pity / what a pity / unfortunately

This is your best bet for expressing, "sad," as you asked in your question. You may want to add a: 真, i.e.: 真可惜.

Answer (score 1):

These words are generally used in different contexts and are difficult to compare
My favorite dog is dead，I feel悲伤or难过。悲伤Generally used for writing，
His family is so poor，I feel心酸Grieve for the misfortunes of others
The champion was mine, but I didn't get it because Low level error，I feel遗憾
The champion was his, but he didn't get it because Low level error。I feel惋惜
可惜Generally used as an exclamation。for example：可惜啊！The champion is not his。If you have to compare悲痛欲绝>悲痛>悲伤>伤心

Comment: right that makes sense